# Given a joint pdf $f(x,y)$ with a given covariance, how does the conditional probability depend on the covariance?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose we have a joint probability density function $f(x,y)$ over the real x-y plane, and further suppose that we know that the $Cov(x,y)>0$. What I am wondering is: is there a relationship between $P(x|y=y_0)$ and $P(x|y=y_1)$ if $y_0<y_1$?

My intuitive sense is that because the covariance is positive, larger values of $x$ mean larger values of $y$, and so if you have a conditional pdf of $x$ with a lower value of $y$, that pdf is going to be more clustered around lower values of $x$, while the opposite can be said for the conditional pdf with a higher value of $y$.

And vice versa, if I have a negative covariance, then the opposite relationship holds, as lower values of $y$ are associated with higher values of $x$.

However, I am struggling to work out such a relationship more formally using the definition of covariance, which I know to be $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. I also have been looking at Hoeffding's covariance identity, but no luck.

I would appreciate any hints or suggestions or references.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but I don't think you can say anything about a conditional probability conditioned on an event with probability zero. Two different PDFs that differ only on a set of measure zero define the same distribution on a random variable.

Comment: @Joe I should've clarified. By conditional on $y=y_0$ I mean the intersection of the pdf $f$ with the plane $y=y_0$.

Comment: Oh, I understood that much. The problem is that two PDFs can be identical on their support except at $y=y_0$, and different on $y=y_0$, yet definite the exact same distribution. I believe you'd have to define a specific limiting process (see for example "Borel–Kolmogorov paradox"). Even if you conditioned on two events with positive measure, I doubt you could make any proof about two specific conditional probabilities. You probably want to try to prove something about conditional expectations instead, but I'm not sure what. What is the context of your problem? Are you making this up?

Comment: @Joe Thank you for sharing the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox, it is absolutely fascinating! I now see that my problem was ill-posed. Ultimately I was trying to make a statement about the stochastic dominance of one conditional pdf vs another for another problem I am working on. When I was trying to think intuitively through this problem, I was drawing pictures of bivariate normals. I now understand that making a general statement about the conditional pdfs for a general probability measure is likely impossible.

Comment: There may be general statements that can be made. You could try to post specifically your context and exactly what you're trying to do, and someone may be able to make suggestions. I'm not sure if you'll want to post that here, or on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions